# how to do calculation in jqgrid PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jqgrid

I have a problem

I have 3 column in [`jqGrid`](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).

Let’s say it `A`,`B`,`C`.

When I insert data, I only have to fill data for column `A` and `B`.

Column `C` is automatically inserted with the value of `A`+`B`.

I'm using jqGrid for PHP and I’m using form to insert the data

Is there a way on how to assign and insert the value of `C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the value of C with a [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) without PHP

```
<table id="#grid-table"></table>

jQuery("#grid-table").jqGrid({
  colNames: ['id', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
  colModel: [
    {name: 'id', key: true, index: 'id', hidden: true},
    {name: 'A', index: 'A'},
    {name: 'B', index: 'B'},
    {name: 'C', formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowData) {
      return rowData.A + rowData.B;
    }}
  ]
})
```